# If input field is checked, add css class

Tags: jquery, input

I'm displaying variable prices, but I only want to display the price of a selected/choosen one.

My code as follows:
Variable prices with input field inside a dropdown menu

```
<ul>
<li class="km-price-options" id="price_option_115_ssize">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="options[price_id][]" id="price_option_115_1" class="price_option_115" value="1" data-price="9.95">
    <span>S Size</span> 
    </label>
</li>
<li class="km-price-options" id="price_option_115_msize">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="options[price_id][]" id="price_option_115_2" class="price_option_115" value="2" data-price="19.25">
    <span>M Size</span> 
    </label>
</li>

<li class="km-price-options" id="price_option_115_xsize">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="options[price_id][]" id="price_option_115_3" class="price_option_115" value="3" data-price="99.50">
    <span>X Size</span> 
    </label>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

Elsewhere on the page the prices

```
<div class="km-item-price"> 

<div class="km-price km-price-option-1">
    <div class="km-item-price">$9.95</div>
</div>

<div class="km-price km-price-option-2 checked">
    <div class="km-item-price">$19.25</div>
</div>

<div class="km-price km-price-option-3">
    <div class="km-item-price">$99.50</div>
</div>

...

</div>
```

By default option 2 is checked.
When e.g. option 1 is selected inside the dropdown menu, I want the `checked` class be removed from `km-price-option-2` and added inside `km-price-option-1`. Same for the imput field `checked="checked"`.

So far my jquery code is as follows:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.km-price').addClass("checked");
    } else {
        $('.km-price').removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

This will add a `checked` class name on all divs with the name `km-price`. 
But it should be limited to a `value="1"` (input). Is this possible with jquery? If yes, how? If there's a better way, I'm all ears. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the value of the radio button to the class you want to add the `checked` class to.

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
    $('.km-price').removeClass("checked");
    $('.km-price-option-' + this.value).addClass("checked");
});
```

Since it's a radio button, you don't need to test `$(this).is(":checked")`. The button you click on is always the one that's checked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a moment and read [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Html:

```
<input type="radio" 
       name="options[price_id][]" 
       id="price_option_115_3" 
       class="price_option_115 js-update-checked" 
       value="3" 
       data-price="99.50"
       data-target=".km-price-option-3">
```

jQuery:

```
$('.js-update-checked').on("click", function(){
  $('.km-price').removeClass("checked");
  var selector = $(this).data("target");
  $(selector).addClass("checked");
});
```

Now adding new radio buttons to the page doesn't cause weird things to happen to this set of radio buttons.  It's also now completely reusable and extensible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example based on `.index()` and using `:eq()`.

```js
$('input:radio').change(function() {
  $('.km-price').removeClass("checked");
  $('.km-price:eq(' + $(this).index('input:radio') + ')').addClass("checked");
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="km-price-options" id="price_option_115_ssize">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="options[price_id][]" id="price_option_115_1" class="price_option_115" value="1" data-price="9.95">
      <span>S Size</span> 
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="km-price-options" id="price_option_115_msize">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="options[price_id][]" id="price_option_115_2" class="price_option_115" value="2" data-price="19.25">
      <span>M Size</span> 
    </label>
  </li>

  <li class="km-price-options" id="price_option_115_xsize">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="options[price_id][]" id="price_option_115_3" class="price_option_115" value="3" data-price="99.50">
      <span>X Size</span> 
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="km-item-price">

  <div class="km-price km-price-option-1">
    <div class="km-item-price">$9.95</div>
  </div>

  <div class="km-price km-price-option-2 checked">
    <div class="km-item-price">$19.25</div>
  </div>

  <div class="km-price km-price-option-3">
    <div class="km-item-price">$99.50</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Learned something new (`.index()` and `:eq()`).  Thank you.